# Cannot undo or redo cutting and pasting actions in the editor

Tags: bug, editor

When I cut something, I expect the editor to act as if I pressed the backspace (aka delete) button. When I paste something, I expect the editor to act as if I just typed something.

But the editor here doesn't actually work like that currently. If the undo/redo buttons (or their shortcuts) are used, then the action done by cutting or pasting is "forgotten". (Unless the only action done was pasting, which fails to enable the undo button/shortcut in the first place.)

This is extremely frustrating to me because I use the undo/redo keyboard shortcuts a lot, almost instinctively. And I do a lot of pasting.

I'm surprised that I can't find another question here on Meta complaining about this. It's a pretty big annoyance, and it's easy to reproduce. (Just paste something into a blank editor, for example.)

Unfortunately, I doubt that I would be able to avoid this problem by avoiding the editor, because there are plenty of times that I paste something into a blank editor and instantly want to undo the action (but I can't, as I said before).

The strange thing is that bolding, for example, works fine with undo and redo.

---

Side note: I am on a Mac, but I am shown the Windows keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + key). This is wrong on Mac, as the correct key combo is <kbd>command</kbd> (aka <kbd>⌘</kbd>) + key

Comment: Hmm, undo/redo does appear to be completely screwed on my end.

Comment: I have experienced these types of issues for as long as I have used the site. The workaround is to just not use ctrl+z :)

Comment: Related reports: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32924/ and   http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259819/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167885/  This is a known issue since 2009.